# Can I make Visual Studio 2017 stop indenting braces for case?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio indents braces in case like this:

```
switch(variable)
{
    case 0:
        {
            // some code
            break;
        }
}
```

However I would like it better without indentation:

```
switch(variable)
{
    case 0:
    {
        // some code
        break;
    }
}
```

I was looking through the options, but didn't find the one I want. Did I miss it or is it just not there?

Answer (score 11):

Under Visual Studio

*Options >>  TextEditor >> C# >> Code Style >> Formatting >> Indentation*

is what you are looking for. You will see several options under that menu and set your settings as you wish. In this case, the setting is called **"Indent case contents"**.

Comment: Hmm, this is not exactly what I am looking for. If there are no braces I want content of case to be still indented. So no-indentation should be applied only to braces and not content in case.

Comment: okay my bad. i am using Resharper and it reformats the code (case statement) exactly you would like . I reckon Visual Studio 2017 cannot do that without a extension.

Comment: There is now a "Indent case contents (when block)" option which solves the issue where you still want non-block case statements indented.